# Text wrap issue when pushed to side

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a sort of a dilemma.

I want text to be wrapped initially, on-load, but then when an element (on the sides) width is set to a value (200px) I want it to be moved completely to the side.

The issue is, when the element (a menu) comes in, it just shrinks down the text into the element being pushed to the side. The actually div moves to the side, but the text wraps pushing it downwards.

See, here it's wrapped, that's how it should originally look

[image: no_menu]

Then, when the menu opened, it does this
[image: with_menu]

I've tried using `white-space:nowrap;` but that just removes word wrapping completely.

I've googled into this, but as my issue tends to be I can't really keyword things well, or can't find a good way to solve this.

The end result should be word wrapped text in the beginning, then that element containing the text should be pushed off to the side out of view.

**CSS:**

```
/** Menu CSS **/
#menu-bar-container {
    float:left;
    background-color:#2c2c2c;
    height:100%;
}

 /** "News" element supposed to be pushed to the side **/
.app-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.app-section {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="server-news-container" class="app-content app-scrollable" style="height: 453px; overflow: scroll;">
      <div class="app-section">
           <i id="news-icon" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i> 
           <span id="news-text">In-development, so the app may stop working at any point in time. You have been warned.</span>
           <div id="news-date">Sunday, June 15 2014</div>
      </div>
      <div class="app-section">
           <i id="news-icon" class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i>
           <span id="news-text">Test of the info thing</span> <div id="news-date">Saturday, June 14 2014</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Any help or pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chong Yu pointed out, it's a position issue.
You need to change `content { left:width-of-menu }` when the menu is present, and return it to `content { left:0 }` when the menu collapses.

If you don't explicitly set the width of the menu, you'll need to grab it at somepoint in your code. For ease of explanation, let's assume you set it to 100px wide.

```
.parent.content, .parent.menu { position:relative }
.content { left:0; position:absolute }
.menu { display:none; width:100px }

Menu button is clicked and made visible:
.content { left:100px }
.menu { display:block }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using CSS to move the app-section or app-content.
If you use margin-left to show the menu, it will squeeze as shown in your example.

Try using left with the position of the content.

`left:100px;`

This will preserver the width of the content and just move the position.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `overflow: hidden;` in `.app-content` class.

like below:

```
.app-content {
    position: relative;
}
```